# Insert different Angular2 components programmatically

Tags: inheritance, dynamic, components, angular, composition

I want to programmatically generate a report composed by multiple distinct components from a JSON file like:

```
{
    components: [UserStatsComponent, ActivityChartComponent, NetworkGraphComponent]
}
```

I found this: [Angular2: Creating child components programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830548/angular2-creating-child-components-programmatically)
but my use case differs in that I need to represent different types of components, so I can't use a ngFor in my template because not every component have the same directive.

I'm new to Angular2 so I don't really know how to approach this: First I thought about component inheritance but looks like angular2 annotations are not inherited when extending a component's class. Don't know how to solve this using composition either.

Heard something about the content tag but don't really know if it's relevant to this use case.

tldr; How do I dynamically insert different components from an array?

Comment: su pregunta no es clara... it creates confusion. would you please make it better?

Comment: tldr; How do I dynamically insert different components from an array?

Comment: Do you want to go through json object loop and want to make dynamic components encountered?

Comment: The json object would be parsed somehow inside my main ReportComponent (doesnt matter how I get it), what I mean is that I don't know what children components I will be inserting beforehand.

Comment: If you say you don't know what children component you will be inserting, it means you are saying you don't know how @component decorator will be defined for  each component. So, I think It doesn't look straight and simple answer. But hopefully you can take a look at `DynamicComponentLoader` of angular2. But hope somebody else would be able to answer now or later.

Comment: Yes looks like i'll have to use some kind of factory that takes that json as input and uses the DynamicComponentLoader to populate the view. However, feels like a "generic" or "superclass" component would be the way to go.

Comment: But I wonder with how would you defined @component decorator dynamically for all components to be inserted dynamically. Moreover you don't know how many components will be there in the json object. So pretty awkward as of now.

Comment: Thought of using DynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation()  so the the number of components its no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert components dynamically use the [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: 'Child'
})
class ChildComponent {
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 'Parent (<child id="child"></child>)'
})
class MyApp {
  constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, injector: Injector) {
    dcl.loadAsRoot(ChildComponent, '#child', injector);
  }
}
```